# Multiply 2 matrices so result is lowest

Tags: algorithm, math, matrix

I have
matrix A:

```
[x1, x2, x3, x4]
```

matrix B:

```
[y1,
 y2,
 y3,
 y4]
```

Is it possible to order elements in A and elements in B so that A*B=[z] where z is ALWAYS the smallest possible number without using brute force? Elements can be negative. Does there exist such algorithm? Matrices can be very big.

Comment: This looks more like a dot product than a matrix multiplication to me (although the latter is not incorrect). Are your "matrices" always one row or one column?

Comment: For four elements each this looks trivial: How big can the matrices get? (1st stab: order one ascendantly, the other descendantly.)

Comment: @Nelfeal yes this can be a dot product or also we can think about an equivalent problem (for my purposes) where B*A = C and sum of elements in C is smallest/biggest.

Comment: @greybeard matrices have no limitations, I thought about ordering but does it always work with negative numbers? we can end up multiplying negative times negative

Comment: If all elements are positive, then you can just sort one in ascending order and the other in descending order.  If they can be negative then it's a knapsack problem trying to get as close to 0 as possible, and is NP-hard.

Comment: @MattTimmermans thats what I wanted to hear, thanks

Comment: Although... if you're looking for the most negative answer instead of closest to zero, then sorting still works.

Comment: @MattTimmermans thats interesting... what if I was looking for the biggest number? not the smallest?

Comment: @MattTimmermans because numbers can be both negative and positive in the matrix... not all always positive or all always negative

Comment: @TreningiApp it still works, because adding a large positive constant to every cell just adds a constant to the result.  I guess this just became answer-worthy.  I'll write one...

Answer (score 1):

If all the numbers are positive, then you can just sort one factor in ascending order and the other one in descending order to get the smallest possible result.

If you are looking for the lowest result instead of the one that's closest to zero, then this works even if some of the numbers are negative.

Consider adding a large positive constant to each cell:

(x1+a, x2+a, x3+a, x4+a) • (y1+a, y2+a, y3+a, y4+a)

= (x1,x2,x3,x4) • (y1,y2,y3,y4) + a(x1+x2+x3+x4+y1+y2+y3+y4) +4a<sup>2</sup>

The differences between results of different orders are unchanged, just as the difference between numbers is unchanged.  Since sorting will find the lowest possible result after adding a large enough **a** to each cell, it will also find the lowest possible result without adding anything.

Comment: @greybeard nope: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=expand+%28x1%2Ba%29%28y1%2Ba%29%2B%28x2%2Ba%29%28y2%2Ba%29%2B%28x3%2Ba%29%28y3%2Ba%29%2B%28x4%2Ba%29%28y4%2Ba%29